# Regex replace substring with known first and last word

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string say `"xyz walked his dog abc"`. And I want to remove the substring `"walked his dog"` and just have `"xyz abc"`. How can I do so in bash regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a regular expression is overkill for this particular operation (I recommend [ravoori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16721215/1126841)), it's good to know the syntax if needs change:

```
# Two capture groups, one preceding the string to remove, the other following it
regex='(.*)walked his dog(.*)'
[[ $string =~ $regex ]]
# Elements 1 through n of BASH_REMATCH correspond to the 1st through nth capture
# groups. (Element 0 is the string matched by the entire regex)
string="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure bash:

```
var="xyz walked his dog abc"
echo ${var/walked*dog/}
xyz  abc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array:

```
string="xyz walked his dog abc"

a=( $string )

result="${a[0]} ${a[-1]}"
```

Comment: I realized I framed this question wrongly.The number of words before walked is unknown. The number of words between waled and dog is unknown. The number of words after dog is unknown. All we know is the substring starts with walked and ends with dog.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably using `sed`: `sed -r 's/walked his dog//'` (replace a substring with the empty string). Or using the built-in replacement mechanism (no regex support, though): `a="xyz walked his dog abc"; echo "${a/walked his dog/}"`